# Where is the Infamy Bridge safehouse?

Tags: dying-light

I've just completed the mission where I have to cross the gap on Infamy Bridge to get some sonar doohickey. I've done this before on previous playthroughs and I definitely remember there being a safehouse in a tower on the bridge just before the gap.

However, I've climbed clear to the top (and through both towers on either side) and never got the "Safehouse Unlocked" notification, and I do not see a sleeping bag or stash (assuming there should be one like all the other safehouses).

The "zipline" to cross the gap is/was working incorrectly for whatever reason and was releasing me on the way down (to my death, I tried ~4 times before giving up and just swimming across like a chump). Totally separate issue of course, but this safehouse would have been nice to have so that I wouldn't have had to waste time running from the second closest safehouse.

Is there something I'm not doing to clear it or is there some prerequisite for unlocking it like the others (power box or something)? At this point I'm assuming either (A) a glitch or (B) I'm an idiot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a tough one, and I searched for it for a long time. The safehouse is at the top of one of the towers, but you have to start climbing the *other* tower, then zip-line over to the one with the house at the top. You have to climb up rails on the outside, then later have to climb up wireracks (or whatever those ladder-looking things are) on the inside of one of the towers. It's pretty difficult if you don't know where you're going.

I linked a video, but it wasn't the one I thought of.. I'll find it and re-edit. (The guy in the video I just linked use the grapple -- cheating!)

[Here's a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B7FmpMKptYU) without using the grapple.

Oh, and to make the first jump to climb the tower, you have to do it from the roof of one of the vans there. Just look for an edge to grab onto, then you're on your way.

Comment: Thanks, I'll double check when I get home to make sure there is something there.

Comment: It took me longer to find that safehouse than to do any other single thing in that whole game.

Comment: ok that is still cheating IMHO.. Run up the wires like the rest of us!!! :D

Comment: Cheating... that's the way the area was designed. Running up the wires (which I did try once out of desperation) was just plain suicide for me. (I realize now that was probably a joke... oh well, it's been that kind of day) :)

Comment: @TimS - Was going to double check your answer before accepting and to give my feedback. Turns out it must have been a weird bug... I had been doing other missions after the bridge one just accepting that I don't have a safehouse there. Turns out, when I booted up the game fresh, now it recognized that I've unlocked the safehouse... Shows up on my map now and everything without me having to re-climb the towers.

Comment: The sleeping bag and stash also show where before there was nothing there.

Comment: Weird.. yeah I never got the "Safe Room Unlocked" message, but there was a duffel and sleeping bag there, and it said I was entering a safe room, so I knew I'd found it.